# Concurrent (or parallel) entities (or object like entities) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, concurrency, simulator

I want to model a biological system in Haskell. I am thinking of doing it as following.

- Each cell is an entity; like an object in Object Oriented Programming. This entity can read global variables and update them. Each entity can have more than one function. Each function compute something when some global variables attain certain values. Depending on computation result, each function then update some global variable. Something like hardware description language like VHDL, Bluespec and Verilog.

What is the recommended way of doing it in Haskell. I know basic Haskell quite well. I am also comfortable with Monad and Arrows. I could grasp much when I read reactive banana library.

Comment: First, words "parallel" and "concurrent" have slightly different meaning, so pick one, please. You mentioned "Each function compute when..." It's not clear what does this function compute. Also I think it's important to provide us with information how reliable your model aiming to be. Are you planning to obtain some reliable scientific information or just make some fun? It seems that you described your means, not goals.

Comment: P.S. When I hear words 'objects', 'read and write global variables' etc., I always start wondering why did questioner pick pure functional language. Yes, it is possible to emulate all those things in haskell, but this is not a natural way to use it. It will be certainly more convenient to choose some other language for this.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you describe seems to be [the actors model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model). This is bread and butter of Erlang programming language, but Haskell does not have actors primitives built-in. Quick Cabal inspection gives `hactors` and `simple-actors`, but I can't elaborate on details.

Comment: [Hackage supports search now](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=actors).

Answer (score 1):

If you want an actor system in Haskell, I'd strongly suggest looking at Cloud Haskell. It is based on Erlang/OTP (offering the same message passing concurrency semantics and failure handling).

Caveats though: I am the maintainer. ;)

https://github.com/haskell-distributed
http://haskell-distributed.github.io

Answer (score 1):

Everybody else here has mentioned actors, so I wanted to chime in and mention `pipes-concurrency`, which is a non-distributed form of actors.

Like actors, you have a way to `spawn` a mailbox:

```
import Pipes
import Pipes.Concurrent
import qualified Pipes.Prelude

main = do
    (output, input) <- spawn Unbounded
    ...
```

... send messages to mailboxes:

```
    forkIO $ runEffect $ Pipes.Prelude.stdinLn >-> toOutput output
```

... and read messages off of mailboxes:

```
    runEffect $ runEffect $ fromInput input >-> Pipes.Prelude.stdoutLn
```

You don't even have to use the `pipes` interface.  You can send individual messages at a time using `send`:

```
send :: Output a -> a -> STM Bool
```

... and receive individual messages using `recv`:

```
recv :: Input a -> STM (Maybe a)
```

It comes with an [extended tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-concurrency-2.0.2/docs/Pipes-Concurrent-Tutorial.html) explaining how to use the library.